# Pass value from javascript in jsp to action class in struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

[how can i pass value from javascript to a java class in struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110221/how-can-i-pass-value-from-javascript-to-a-java-class-in-struts2)
This is the link similar to what I want.However it does not work for me.
I have tried something like this.
Struts tag for hidden in jsp is

```
    function redirect(id)
    {
    window.alert("Hello"+id);
    document.getElementById('param_ID').value=id;
    document.forms["./ListAlgorithmAction"].submit();
    }
```

In my action class I have declared getter and setter for the param_ID.But it returns null.

Kindly help.
Thank you.

Comment: can you be a bit clear what you trying to do? and what is not working

Comment: I am trying to display the value of param_ID in the action class.I am getting it as null.Is the code right for redirecting the jsp values to the action class?

Comment: please help.Trying to search for a solution since a long time.

Comment: and what this `param_id`? it should be hidden field to save value and make sure to define a property in your action class with name `param_ID`

Comment: @Soham Quote the line where "param_ID" is added to the form in the question.

Comment: Why do you insist on violating java naming conventions?

Comment: @Soham I guess `./ListAlgorithmAction` is your action name, you should not pass that to the `forms` array. That's bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
<s:hidden id = "param_ID" name="xyz" />
```

Now you should have a getter and setter for xyz property in your struts action.

You should always have name attribute in tags mapped to attributes in Struts action.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is not submitting your `hidden` field, maybe the hidden field is not inside your form element. You can try pass it as a parameter to your url. Try this

```
function redirect(id)
{
     var form = document.forms[0];
     var url = './ListAlgorithmAction?param_ID=' + id;
     form.action = url;
     form.submit();
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: That's what the beauty of question,its letting all of us guessing ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an action and return data you should use struts2-json plugin JQuery script for calling action

```
    var abc = $("#abc").val();
            $.getJSON('youraction.action', {
                variable -name action class : abc,
                            value to be passed:value,

        //and so on
            }, function(data) {


        //your processing code
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

If you want to just call action you may want to use $.ajax in place of $.getJson

If you want to use struts 2-json then you would also need to change your struts.xml i.e

```
<result name="success" type="json"></result>
```

It's worth a go

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by appending the Action class from JavaScript function and appending the URL parameters as shown below:

```
<a href="(<%actionClassName%>.action?<%URLParms%>" />
```